# Bootstrap list-group menu expands on-click, but does not collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a sidebar list-group menu in Bootstrap that expands on the first click, but the second click doesn't collapse the menu back, and clicking on other items simply expands them as well without collapsing anything.

```
    <div id="accordion" class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#listofOptions">List Header 1</a>
            <div class="list-group-collapse collapse" id="listofOptions">
                <a class="list-group-item" href="#">List Item 1</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" href="#">list Item 2</a>
            </div>
        <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#listofOptions2">List Header 2</a>
            <div class="list-group-collapse collapse" id="listofOptions2">
                <a class="list-group-item" href="#">List Item 1</a>
                <a class="list-group-item" href="#">list Item 2</a>
            </div>      
    </div>
```

I'm using standard bootstrap.min.js and none of my custom JavaScript is touching the .collapse scripts, at least not intentionally.

Comment: This list-group menu code looks good using jQuery 1.11.0, bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js from bootstrapcdn.com. You could try posting a fiddle (or similar) with more of your code for review.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sidhenimh/jasajdvr/ Here's a fiddle; the fiddle is working, so I'm not sure what's up with the live version. @khilley

Comment: Hmm... my fiddle of it worked too. Any chance you can share a URL of the live version?

Comment: @khilley Unfortunately, it's on an intranet currently while in development, so I can't link to the live one. I loaded the externals in a different order on the fiddle, and tried swapping them around on live. No difference. The only variable is the live one is on a CMS and is automatically generating the id tags - but I checked the generated source and those all match up.

Comment: I copied the live generated code into the Fiddle and it still works. Time to scour for stray tags in the larger document.

Comment: With your live version, check to see if you are calling the jquery.js before the bootstrap.min.js. Also, if you are minifying your CSS or JS files in live, suggest trying to call them individually instead.

Comment: Found the issue - the CMS was generating the call to the CDN for jQuery twice. Fixed that, and the code works correctly.

Comment: Nice job! You should enter an official "Answer" to your question and accept it (if you're able to do so) so that other folks here know it's been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this issue, check and make sure that your CMS isn't duplicating a call to any of the jQuery libraries twice. I found that due to a typo, my header was repeating and the double-call was causing several minor - but annoying - bugs.